# Firebase Rules (Real-time Database). Check if post title contains user ID

Tags: regex, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

My posts contain user id for example, a user with a userId: “abcd1234z” would have a post of name “abcd1234z-1”. I can’t get the write rule check if the post title ($child) contains the userId within the name. I tried .contains and .matches options but must not be formatting the regex correctly.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "cloud": {
      "news": {
        ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        ".write": "auth.uid != null",
      }
    },
    "forum": {
      "posts": {
        "$child": {
          ".read": "auth.uid != null",
          ".write": "auth.uid != null && $child.matches(/*+request.auth.uid/)"
          "$uid": {
            ".write": "auth.uid != null && $uid === auth.uid",
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently tested this with `.contains` instead of matches and that worked, so have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67220633/firebase-write-to-parent-rule-if-new-child-key-contains-string?noredirect=1#comment119145872_67220633) and the screenshot in my comment. In your case it should be something like: `$child.contains(auth.uid)`.

---

**Update**: my comments/screenshots from the (now deleted) question:

> This seems to work for me:
> [image]
> Can you show what doesn't work about your case?

Comment: I tried this originally but it didn’t work, for some reason I had to remove request as it wasn’t a recognised variable?. So it works now using: $child.contains(auth.uid). Thanks!

Comment: Good catch. `request` only exists on Firestore. In Realtime Database rules, the `auth` is a top-level variable.

Comment: The question linked to appears to be removed.

Comment: Good Catch. I added the comment/pic from there to my answer here...